# How does Airbnb route each article?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes, url-routing

I am making a website with **Ruby on Rails**, referencing Airbnb, and I found it difficult to make the following URL structure.

> https://www.airbnb.com/help/article/767/what-is-the-resolution-center

In this URL, it seems that there is an article resource under help, so 767 is the ID of the article. In addition, after the ID, there is the name of the page in the URL.

```
scope '/help' do
  resources :articles
end
```

By doing this, I was able to route until this part.

> /help/articles/'page_id'

But I have no idea what to do from here.

I generated article model(title:string, content:text), and I am guessing that each article(title and content) is displayed according to the id.

---

Here's my questions.

- How does Airbnb route page_name after the article ID?
- In the case that the title and content in the article table are displayed, how  do you put hyperlinks or internationalize the contents with I18n?
- Also, please tell me if my guess is wrong in the first place, and tell me how Airbnb routes each article.

---

Thank you.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/norman/friendly_id gem

Answer (score 5):

To tell Rails to accept request under URL like `/help/article/767/what-is-the-resolution-center` is actually very easy when you do use `get` instead of nested `resources`:

```
get '/help/article/:id/:slug', to: 'help_atricles#show', as: 'help_article'
```

Given the above URL, Rails would extract the `id` and `slug` from the URL and route the request to the `show` method of a `HelpArticlesController`.

That controller method could be as simple as:

```
def show
  @article = HelpArticle.find(params[:id])
end
```

And to build such URLs you can use the `help_article_path` helper method defined by the `as: 'help_article'` part:

```
<%= link_to(
      @article.title, 
      help_article_path(
        id:   @article.id, 
        slug: @article.title.parameterize
      )
    ) %>
```

Read more about this [routing method in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code)

Btw. I didn't use the `slug` part of the URL because it feels to me like it makes the URL look nicer and might be SEO relevant, but it feels useless from the application's point of view. You might want to use the `slug` part to identify the locale in which the article should be shown if you do not want to use the browser's locale setting.

Comment: Another common approach is to compare the given `params[:slug]` to the actual `slug` and redirect to the latter if they don't match. This makes the slug part optional when accessing the resource but ensures a consistent URL.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for answering!! 
I tried to do what you wrote(I did article_pass, articles#show, instead what you wrote because I have already had articles controller), and I had this error.

ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method `article' for #<#<Class:0x00000005115738>:0x000000072046b0>

Where should I fix? I think that the model is the problem but I don't know exactly.

Comment: Ups, I am sorry. It is my fault. I updated my answer to fix that. In the view, you have to use `@article` instead of just `article`

Comment: Okay I did but am getting another error.
    
    syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
    @ article.title, @ article_path(id: @ article.id, slug: @ articl
    
My view file is this.

    <% provide(:title, "Lenga Help Center") %>'
    <h1>Help Center</h1>
    <p>How can we help you?</p>
    
    <%= link_to article.title, article_path(id: article.id, slug: 
    article.title.parameterize) %>
    

with all the @ in front of article.

Comment: It looks like you have whitespaces between `@` and the variables names. That is not correct, just remove the whitespace and write `@article` as one word.